# Node.js — Maximum call stack size exceeded, even with process.nextTick()

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write a module for "chainable" Express.js validation:

```
const validatePost = (req, res, next) => {
  validator.validate(req.body)
    .expect('name.first')
      .present('The parameter is required')
      .string('The parameter must be a string')
    .go(next);
};

router.post('/', validatePost, (req, res, next) => {
  return res.send('Validated!');
});
```

The code of `validator.validate` (simplified for brevity):

```
const validate = (data) => {

  let validation;

  const expect = (key) => {
    validation.key = key;

    // Here I get the actual value, but for testing purposes of .present() and
    // .string() chainable methods it returns a random value from a string,
    // not string and an undefined
    validation.value = [ 'foo', 123, void 0 ][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
    return validation;
  };

  const present = (message) => {
    if (typeof validation.value === 'undefined') {
      validation.valid = false;
      validation.errors.push({ key: validation.key, message: message });
    }
    return validation;
  };

  const string = (message) => {
    if (typeof validation.value !== 'string') {
      validation.valid = false;
      validation.errors.push({ key: validation.key, message: message });
    }
    return validation;
  };

  const go = (next) => {
    if (!validation.valid) {
      let error = new Error('Validation error');
      error.name = 'ValidationError';
      error.errors = validation.errors;

      // I even wrap async callbacks in process.nextTick()
      process.nextTick(() => next(error));
    }
    process.nextTick(next);
  };

  validation = {
    valid: true,
    data: data,
    errors: [],
    expect: expect,
    present: present,
    string: string,
    go: go
  };

  return validation;

};
```

The code works fine for short chains, returning a proper error object. However if I chain a lot of methods, say:

```
const validatePost = (req, res, next) => {
  validator.validate(req.body)
    .expect('name.first')
      .present('The parameter is required')
      .string('The parameter must be a string')
    .expect('name.first') // Same for testing
      .present('The parameter is required')
      .string('The parameter must be a string')
    // [...] 2000 times
    .go(next);
};
```

Node.js throws `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Note that I wrapped my async callback `.go(next)` in a `process.nextTick()`.

Comment: Coincidentally I've been studying all night about various continuation passing styles and using trampolines in languages (like JavaScript) that don't support TCO. I was probably reading about `process.nextTick` the same time you posted this question when I learned that it's used to effectively create a `while` loop using the event queue ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method Chaining Overflow**

From your [full code paste](http://pastebin.com/gAceVtB1)

```
validate({ name: { last: 'foo' }})
    // Duplicate this line ~2000 times for error
    .expect('name.first').present().string()
    .go(console.log);
```

You simply cannot chain that many methods in a single expression.

In an [isolated test](https://repl.it/EfTi/0), we show that this has nothing to do with recursion or `process.nextTick`

```
class X {
  foo () {
    return this
  }
}

let x = new X()

x.foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo()
.foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo()
.foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo()
...
.foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo().foo()

// RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Using 64-bit Chrome on OSX, the method chaining limit is **6253** before a stack overflow happens. This likely varies per implementation.

---

**Lateral thinking**

A method-chaining DSL seems like a nice way to specify validation properties for your data. It's unlikely you'd need to chain more than a couple dozen lines in a given validation expression, so you shouldn't be too worried about the limit.

Aside from that, a completely different solution might be altogether better. One example that immediately comes to mind is [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/). Instead of writing validation with code, would write it declaratively with data.

Here's a quick JSON schema example

```
{
  "title": "Example Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
      "description": "Age in years",
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    }
  },
  "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

There's effectively no limit on how big your schema can be, so this should be suitable to solve your problem.

**Other advantages**

- Schema is portable so other areas of your app (eg testing) or other consumers of your data can use it
- Schema is JSON so it's a familiar format and users don't need to learn new syntax or API

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have a lot of time to look at this, but I did notice a pretty big problem. You have a single-branch if statement that leads to `next` being called **twice** when `!validator.valid` is `true`. In general, single-branch `if` statements are a code smell.

This might not be the reason you're experiencing a stack overflow, but it's a likely culprit.

(Code changes appear in **bold**)

```
const go = (next) => {
  if (!validation.valid) {
    let error = new Error('Validation error');
    error.name = 'ValidationError';
    error.errors = validation.errors;
    process.nextTick(() => next(error));
  }
  else {
    process.nextTick(next);
  }
};
```

Some people use `return` to cheat with `if` too. This also works, but it sucks

```
const go = (next) => {
  if (!validation.valid) {
    let error = new Error('Validation error');
    error.name = 'ValidationError';
    error.errors = validation.errors;
    process.nextTick(() => next(error));
    return; // so that the next line doesn't get called too
  }
  process.nextTick(next);
};
```

I think the entire `go` function is expressed better like this ...

```
const go = (next) => {
  // `!` is hard to reason about
  // place the easiest-to-understand, most-likely-to-happen case first
  if (validation.valid) {
    process.nextTick(next)
  }
  // very clear if/else branching
  // there are two possible outcomes and one block of code for each
  else {
    let error = new Error('Validation error');
    error.name = 'ValidationError';
    error.errors = validation.errors;
    // no need to create a closure here
    process.nextTick(() => next(error));
    process.nextTick(next, error);
  }
};
```

---

**Other remarks**

You have other single-branch `if` statements in your code too

```
const present = (message) => {
  if (typeof validation.value === 'undefined') {
    // this branch only performs mutations and doesn't return anything
    validation.valid = false;
    validation.errors.push({ key: validation.key, message: message });
  }
  // there is no `else` branch ...

  return validation;
};
```

This one is less offensive, but I still think it's harder to reason about once you gain an appreciation for `if` statements that always have an `else`. Consider the ternary operator (`?:`) that forces both branches. Also consider languages like Scheme where a *True* and *False* branch are always required when using `if`.

Here's how I'd write your `present` function

```
const present = (message) => {
  if (validation.value === undefined) {
    // True branch returns
    return Object.assign(validation, {
      valid: false,
      errors: [...validation.errors, { key: validation.key, message }]
    })
  }
  else {
    // False branch returns
    return validation
  }
};
```

It's an opinionated remark, but I think it's one worth considering. When you have to return to this code and read it later, you'll thank me. Of course once your code is in this format, you can sugar the hell out of it to remove a lot of syntactic boilerplate

```
const present = message =>
  validation.value === undefined
    ? Object.assign(validation, {
        valid: false,
        errors: [...validation.errors, { key: validation.key, message }]
      })
    : validation
```

Advantages

- Implicit `return` effectively forces you to use a single expression in your function – this means you cannot (easily) over-complicate your functions
- Ternary expression is an *expression*, not a *statement* – `if` does not have a return value so use of ternary works well with the implicit return
- Ternary expression limits you to one expression per branch – again, forces you to keep your code simple
- Ternary expression forces you to use both `true` *and* `false` branches so that you always handle *both* outcomes of the predicate

And yes, there's nothing stopping you from using `()` to combine multiple expressions into one, but the point isn't to reduce every function to a single expression – it's more of an ideal and nice to use when it works out. If at any time you feel readability was affected, you can resort to `if (...) { return ... } else { return ... }` for a familiar and friendly syntax/style.

Comment: Great tips, thanks for pointing out the absence of the `return` statement, but unfortunately neither the `return` fix, nor other tips solved the problem :( It just seems like excessive `return validation;` (or if `Validation` is a `Class` — `return this;`) causes too much async stuff going out, flooding the call stack.

Comment: Nah, there has to be something else going on then. Have you considered getting the code to work outside of the the middleware context first? If you're still stuck later, I can take a look at it after I wake up.

Comment: Ok, so the full code is here: http://pastebin.com/gAceVtB1 I've changed my logic from simple object to a class, the problem persists even outside of the middleware context.

Comment: Anton, **re: line 91**, `Duplicate this line ~2000 times for error` – that's the problem; you can't chain that many methods in a single expression. Here's an isolated example: [https://repl.it/EfTi/0](https://repl.it/EfTi/0) – my browser stack overflows after 6253 chained methods. If you remove one `.foo()` from my paste and you'll see that it works.

Comment: You shouldn't perceive this as a problem tho. If users would be expected to write even 100 or 200 chained methods to validate their object, that's already problematic. There are much better, declarative ways to do so. One example that comes to mind is [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/).

Comment: Thanks, almost what I thought. It's not like I'm expecting myself to write ~2000 validation lines or anything, but I was worried that this error might happen if many concurrent requests happen via this validation middleware. If you don't mind post another answer to the original question so that I can accept it.

Comment: Ok, I added another answer. I'm sorry that the answer might not have been what you're looking for, but I hope you have a better understanding of how to work with your problem ^_^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129704/discussion-between-anton-egorov-and-naomik).